# Power BI - column with two different data types

Tags: powerbi

I want to convert this column to a %(see image). The column has a decimal value but also a text string as well. I want to show the sales utilization in Power BI in a Matrix but want a % and not the ugly decimal.

The column is fixed to Text rather than a number so its difficult to do so. Would welcome any suggestions on a work around.

[image: Labour Utilization Image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a Calculated Column using DAX. This column data type will be Decimal. Just change the Format to Percentage.

```
Calculated Column = IFERROR(VALUE('Table'[Column1]),BLANK())
```

[image]